# Capture black and white photo from native Android Camera App

Tags: android, camera

I have found good examples on how to call the native Android camera app using an intent, and I know you can set the app to take black and white photos using the UI, but I couldn't find a way to take a BW photo using the intent. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check on the [Camera class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) that is provided in case you need more precise control over the way a picture is taken. If you're interested in color effects, there are some "pre-defined" color effects that can be found in the [Camera.Parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html) class. Hope you find your way now :-)